# opengl application listening/recieving data from a socket connection?

Tags: ios, opengl, networking, glut, asyncsocket

I'm looking to send data from iPhone app to desktop OpenGL application using sockets connection. e.g. location of texture,

I have the OpenGL application running on the desktop.
And a separate socket application for desktop and iPhone where I can send/receive the data.

But I'm not sure how to combine the sockets application and OpenGL application for the desktop.

The desktop OpenGL application can only receive data once, and then it gets into `glutMainLoop()`.

Comment: Check this out. It's not related to sockets, therefore I'm not posting it as an answer but you can call other functions while glutMainLoop() is executing of course. http://www.kanersan.com/myfiles/Volcano.cpp

Answer (score 3):

> The desktop opengl application can only recieve data once, and then it gets into glutMainLoop().

That's because you wrote it that way. Your application does exactly and only what you tell it. You put your "get data from socket" code outside of the main loop.

You can simply set up a timer function with `glutTimerFunc`. In that function, you check to see if there's more data, and if there is, you store it and call `glutPostRedisplay` to make GLUT call its display method again.

Personally, I would suggest avoiding GLUT for an application like this, where you need control over the main loop. [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) will be much more useful to you, since it's easier to simply check the socket to see if there's new data after rendering a frame. You might even want a threaded solution, though that's a little much for a simple case like this.